# How to stop Sublime Text 3 from changing font size on different sized screens

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite, external-display, sublime-text-3, ipad

I've recently just installed AirDisplay 3 on my iPad so I can use it as a second screen for my MacBook Pro retina (with Yosemite).

It works brilliantly with everything so far bar ST3. As soon as I drag a ST window over onto the iPad's screen it resets the font size to something much larger (>double).

It only does this with Sublime Text so I'm assuming it's specific to a setting in the program itself.

So is there a way to disable this 'feature' of ST3?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

By setting

```
"gpu_window_buffer"
```

from auto to false

i.e.

```
"gpu_window_buffer": false,
```

the issue was fixed.